# issue while installing apache with yum

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, repository

When i run yum install httpd-devel i get this :

```
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7Server&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=$infra error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Erreur inconnue"


 One of the configured repositories failed (Inconnu),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:


Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7Server/x86_64
```

I'm using rhel 7 how can i solve this ?

Comment: set up a reachable dns server in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Are you using RHEL7 or CentOS7?  The error you posted suggests you have a CentOS mirror setup as a yum repo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the server with Red Hat before you can use RHEL repositories.

If you have an active redhat subscription, then perform the following:

```
subscription-manager register --username <username> --password <password>
```